# Vue + Rollup: Unused vars error on build for plugin

Tags: javascript, vue.js, rollup, rollupjs, vuejs3

[image: Error image]

I am building a plugin inside a Vue 3 installation in `src/plugin`. I am using RollupJS to build my plugin with rollup-plugin-vue to compile the Vue templates.
This is my plugin's entry point:
`index.js`

```js
import Test from './components/Test.vue'

const install = (app) => {
    app.directive('testdirective', {
        mounted(el){
            el.style.background = "orange"
            el.style.padding = "1em"
        }
    })
}

export default install
export {
    Test
}
```

and the test vue file
`Test.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div>
      <h1 v-testdirective>Test Heading</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

**Build configuration**
`rollup.config.js`

```js
import vue from 'rollup-plugin-vue'

export default {
    input: 'src/index.js',
    output:[
        {
            file: 'dist/bundle.js',
            format: 'esm'
        }
    ],
    plugins:[
        vue()
    ],
    external: ['vue']
}
```

I tried test code to see if the builds worked, but I am getting the error in `dist/bundle.js` (Image attached at top of this post)
Also, if I remove the empty script and style tags in `Test.vue` then I get only these errors:
[image: Test.vue error if no script or style]

But I will be needing those when I am actually building the plugin. I don't know how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to either add a rule via eslint to ignore `no-undefined-vars`, but it may be a good idea to have those in, and just flag the vars where you define them.

I believe this should work without changing the eslint rules

```js
/* exported _ctx*/
let _ctx = {}

/* exported _cache*/
let _cache = {}
```

Comment: Adding an eslint rule might work for me but I wouldn't want people using the plugin to have to do that.
Defining them like you said might work, I might have to tap into the build process of rollup though. Would I need to make a rollup plugin myself?